# Write a second order differential equation for which y(t)= 2 cost- t is a solution and verify

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to write a second order differential equation for which $y(t) = 2\cos t - t$ is a solution (and verify the solution).

I've tried taking derivatives and finding the relationship between $y$, $y'$ and $y''$. I got the equation $y'' + y = -t$. However, this does not seem to be a correct solution. Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: Nope, it's fine, unless you were asked for a homogeneous second order differential equation. In that case, no constant coefficient 2nd order equation would work, and it would become a pretty interesting problem. Is this a sophomore level class?

Comment: Do they want you to have initial/boundary conditions? I think the solution to the differential equation you wrote will include a sine term without conditions

Answer (score 1):

You have done fine. What makes you think it is wrong?